# SDL returns no output when I try to print statements using cout

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, sdl-2

I installed the MinGW version of SDL from their [website](https://libsdl.org).

I created a sample piece of code just to test if I could include the library without any errors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL INIT FAILED" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "SDL INIT SUCCEEDED" << endl;

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I also created a Makefile:

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project
OBJS = main.cpp

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Isrc\includes

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = -Lsrc\lib

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our exectuable
OBJ_NAME = main

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

If I don't include the `int argc, char* argv[]` inside of `int main()` and try to **ming32-make**, it throws an error:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\C++\SDL_test> mingw32-make

g++ main.cpp -Isrc\includes -Lsrc\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src\lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): in function `main_getcmdline':
/Users/valve/release/SDL2/SDL2-2.26.2-source/foo-x64/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:82: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:26: all] Error 1
```

When I include `int argc, char* argv[]`, it doesn't give any errors but doesn't print anything either.

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\C++\SDL_test> mingw32-make
g++ main.cpp -Isrc\includes -Lsrc\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main
C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\C++\SDL_test>
```

When I use `make` instead of `mingw32-make`, the output remains the same.

I am using VSCode and I have included the header files and lib files in an src folder in the same directory as my script and also moved the SDL2.dll file in the root folder:

[image: code files]

My C++ Configuration on VSCode:

```
Compiler Path: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Compiler Arguments: 
IntelliSense mode: gcc-x64 (legacy) // Because using anything else says the the mode is incompatible with the compiler path.
Include path:
${workspaceFolder}/**
${workspaceFolder}/src/includes
```

I had also recieved ***SDL.h: file or directory not found*** errors before this and I fixed them by creating the Makefile.

Is there something I'm missing? Does SDL not output to stdout, because I've seen tutorials online and they are able to get outputs from `cout` fine on them.

I am expecting cout to work when I run the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Wl,-subsystem,windows` (aka `-mwindows`) hides the console window, and with it all output. Remove it, and use it only in the release builds.

> `-w` suppresses all warnings

This is extremely unwise. Prefer `-Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated` to enable most common warnings, plus `-std=c++20 -pedantic-errors` to enforce standard compliance (replace `20` with the latest version supported by your compiler).

---

As suggested by @keltar, you might be able to get output even from a program built with `-mwindows` if you redirect it to a file, using `my_program.exe >output.txt`.

Comment: I've followed your instructions and made changes to the compiler flags but I still do not see any output in my console. I do not have any external console windows open up either. I have tried adding `-mswindows` as a compiler flag and redirected the output of the exe to a file but the file is empty.

Edit: I get warnings about `int argc` and `char* argv[]` being empty but other than that no other warnings.

Comment: @c0ncatenate Did you rebuild the .exe after removing this flag from the makefile? Delete it, then run make again.

Comment: I did rebuild the program. Deleted the old exe and ran `make` again. New exe got created. `./main.exe` returns nothing and `./main.exe > out.txt` creates a text file with nothing in it.

Comment: Can you show the make output when rebuilding the program? Did you try removing the flag completely, maybe the part about file redirect is wrong.

Comment: When I run make, this is what it says: `g++ main.cpp -Isrc\includes -Lsrc\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main`

Comment: @c0ncatenate It should work then.

Comment: When I run main.exe, I get nothing in the output. No couts no errors no nothing

Comment: @c0ncatenate A dll issue perhaps? Try starting the program by double-clicking it in the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The issue was that I hadn't installed SDL2 the right way. I installed MSYS2 and used it to install MinGW-w64.
I then used the Msys2 command-line interface to install SDL2 using these commands:

`pacman -Syu`
`pacman -Su`
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2`

This installed the header and lib files for SDL in their proper locations. I was then able to include those files in my code.

I changed the main function from `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` to `int WinMain(int argc, char* argv[])` because I'm on Windows and this helps get rid of the `undefined reference to WinMain` error.

My working code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int WinMain(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL INIT FAILED" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "SDL INIT SUCCESSFUL" << endl;
}
```